# Using Android phone as microphone for R PI B+

Tags: usb, hardware, audio

I'm planning to use Jasper for voice control on my Raspberry Pi B+.

However, there are no microphone sockets and I do not have a USB mic.

I would like to know if there is any way I could use my android phone (Note 3) as a mic (wired or wireless).

Comment: Is this what you have in mind http://www.instructables.com/id/Voice-control-your-PC-from-your-phone-android/ or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sns.myControl&hl=en or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifiddrcwgdo

Comment: unless you are doing it for the fun of interfacing with an android phone, isn't it easier to spend $5 and buy a usb microphone?

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML5 WebRTC to record audio, That way you can use any modern device (not iOS). The web browser can capture audio and send it to the pi via apache/lighttpd/etc. There are already many stackoverflow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571044/how-to-record-webcam-and-audio-using-webrtc-and-a-server-based-peer-connection)s.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything about how the audio's captured, gets transported to the Pi, or is processed by the Pi. Can you expand it to provide a more useful answer?

Comment: Certainly an improvement, but it doesn't tell me *how*. It's like someone asking how to turn on a high power LED and telling them 'use a transistor'. It's *right*, but it's not *useful*.

Comment: @goobering the OP asked "if" not "how" but I have lined to existing solutions on stackexchange.